# USB Redirection to thin clients

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, terminal-server, usb, thin-client

I'm experiencing a problem with a client situation. We switched a user of theirs to a thin client (specifically, with a WYSE C10LE). The thin client connects to a Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual terminal server, running Service Pack 1.

The user needs to be able to use an SD card reader (indeterminate model, bought at a retail store) to do his job. However, the client setup does not support USB redirection, as we have discovered. RemoteFX is not an option since it cannot be installed on a virtual host, as Hyper-V is a dependency. And from what I can tell, both from searching and calling Wyse directly, is that we will require their TCX software to be installed to run this. Obviously we don't want to tell the client they need to purchase an additional thing to make it work.

Is there a model of thin client we can switch them to which would not require a service on the Terminal server back end to be running to obtain USB redirection? My boss says he was able to use USB redirection for printers with no special effort on some HP thin clients (on another client, a few years ago), but without model # specifics I'm not sure what that's attributable to. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the HP passed through the USB device?  Or did it simply mount the SD card on the client and map drives through the client?  There are lots of clients that support drive mapping, but a full USB pass-through is a lot trickier.

Comment: Does this help at all? http://community.wyse.com/forum/showthread.php?1612-S10-USB-mapping

Comment: Wow, I made a major oversight in the OP, which I've now edited: the devices my boss was able to redirect were printers, not card readers.

Unfortunately the thread you linked doesn't help because the poster in that thread is using a Citrix backend, but thanks for helping! :)

Comment: Ah, my mistake, but won't the general idea work for you?  I haven't used Wyse clients but I would be pretty surprised if they don't have a way to map storage through the RDP client.  Almost every other RDP client I have seen has that facility.  Worst case you could probably PXE boot those clients with Linux and use FreeRDP or something.

Comment: That's what's surprising about this, the WYSE clients seem pretty helpless. Theoretically we could PXE boot but that wouldn't fit the client's needs (he needs to open pictures on the SD cards and mail them in Outlook), which worked fine on his desktop workstation - so we're losing face already, but even worse on a weird solution like that. Currently we mount it as a shared drive on somebody else's workstation and that's also weird.

We may have no option but to buy the TCX software. If we could find a thin client that doesn't need it though, we can swap them out and use the WYSE elsewhere.